# Syntactic explanation of "delivery by today"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, formality

I am in the middle of a syntax analysis of some informal language usage and someone used...

"..., delivery by today,..."

After a noun, in this case a package. It was clear that the phrase described when the object would be delivered, but when explaining it, I struggled to do so.

How would someone explain the phrase "..., delivery by today,..." as describing the package, when it is its own noun phrase or how would one chart it?

It seemed to fill the role that "delivered by today" would have, so I could even see it serving as the verb. Is there a convention in English I can cite for it being in the form delivery over delivered to explain this form?

Also, this is my first question on here, so if I should have gone about it differently, please let me know. I really appreciate this community.

Comment: Hello, Aaron. 'Delivery by Thursday / next Monday / 3 pm ...' is an idiom. It's probably a deleted form of 'We guarantee delivery by tomorrow', 'You will receive [your] delivery by tomorrow',  'Delivery will take place by tomorrow'  or the like, but whatever its origins, we're stuck (no, graced) with it. Idioms by definition have non-standard word sense, grammar, or both, and it has been argued that there's little point in trying to use normal methods of grammatical analysis on the extra-grammatical ones.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am new at some of this but am learning as much as I can. Inherently non-standard usage is so easy to understand as a L1 user, but so hard to find acceptable words to describe in academic settings.